# How to make dialog close work with generated views?

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces

I have a Primefaces project where all the views are generated via Netbeans.
Some of the views are edited and made into common used one, to make it more transparant. My problem is, that the VIEW part of the CRUD is one of the common ones, so it's referenced like this:

myView/myListView.xhtml:

```
<p:dialog id="InvoiceViewDlg" widgetVar="InvoiceViewDialog" modal="true" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" header="#{bundle.ViewInvoiceTitle}">
    <ui:include src="View.xhtml"/> 
</p:dialog>
```

referencing myView/View.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:components="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/Components"
      xmlns:my="http://mywork.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition>
        <ui:include src="/view/form/formView.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="item" value="#{invoiceController.selected}" />
            <ui:param name="formType" value="invoice"/>
            <ui:param name="controller" value="#{invoiceController}"/>  
        </ui:include>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

referening /view/form/formView.xhtml and this is the problem:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Close}" onclick="PF('FormViewDialog').hide()" styleClass="cancelButton"/>
```

formView is referenced on every View form and sadly the Close button (not the X, that is working) isn't working, because of the bad reference in the onclick event. I have no idea how make this work for every form... Has anyone any idea?

EDIT:

I edited my myView/View.xhtml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:components="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/Components"
      xmlns:my="http://mywork.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition>
        <ui:include src="/view/form/formView.xhtml">
            <ui:param name='dialogname' value='InvoiceViewDialog'/>
            <ui:param name="item" value="#{invoiceController.selected}" />
            <ui:param name="formType" value="invoice"/>
            <ui:param name="controller" value="#{invoiceController}"/>  
        </ui:include>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

And my /view/form/formView.xhtml:

```
        <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Close}" onclick="PF('#{dialogname}')).hide()" styleClass="cancelButton"/>
```

Sadly, this is the error I'm still getting:

[image: UI error]

Comment: You can add `<ui:param name='dialogname' value='InvoiceViewDialog'/>` and change the button to `onclick="PF('#{dialogname}').hide()"`

Comment: Or make it a composite component...

Comment: Where exactly should I add the <ui:param name='dialogname' value='InvoiceViewDialog'/>? In the myView/View.xhtml?

Comment: Hm... added into my myView/View.xhtml, but I still getting error (editing my question)

Comment: Sorry, I added one ")" after '#{dialogname}', now it's working :) Holger, if you add this as answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but you seem to be using `p:layout`.. this is deprecated but more importantly there are some bugs in a sub version of PF 6 (I believe 6.2). You might want to eliminate / replace it.